# Getting an error in Docker, “requested experimental feature exec.meta.security is not supported by build server”

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

We use some experimental features of buildkit in our `Dockerfile`s, most notably the cache mounts. Today, all builds stopped working with message:

```
requested experimental feature exec.meta.security  is not supported by build server, please update
```

The following is the relevant output of `journalctl -u docker`:

```
Apr 27 12:50:42 laptop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302466366+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"\"" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302489224+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302545282+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{ 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302556961+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302595944+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420d068e0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:07 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:07.302697663+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420d068e0, READY" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:08 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:08.096360518+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserv
Apr 27 13:05:08 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:08.096425639+02:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 200
Apr 27 13:05:09 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:09.164531606+02:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.134327397+02:00" level=info msg="Layer sha256:c5436d94671d3b039ae327cbd70bcc7247156b1db1a94c6b5c96d20eb5306fe0 cleaned up"
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.264799407+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to { 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.264831645+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420d068e0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.264898501+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420d068e0, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.264926781+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420d068e0, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:05:10 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:05:10.302876165+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.transportMonitor exits due to: context canceled" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415336758+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"\"" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415358861+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415401731+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{ 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415420573+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415455123+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42075b950, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:00 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:00.415512072+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42075b950, READY" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:03 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:03.557274713+02:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers: [nameserv
Apr 27 13:06:03 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:03.557342307+02:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers: [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 200
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T11:06:05Z" level=error msg="fatal error: requested experimental feature exec.meta.security  is not supported by build server, please update \
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: panic: requested experimental feature exec.meta.security  is not supported by build server, please update
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: goroutine 1 [running]:
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: main.main()
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]:         /src/frontend/dockerfile/cmd/dockerfile-frontend/main.go:26 +0x34f
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:05.835385263+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42075b950, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:05.835517263+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42075b950, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:05.835541307+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to { 0  <nil>}. Err :connection error: desc = \
Apr 27 13:06:05 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:05.835658016+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42075b950, TRANSIENT_FAILURE" module=grpc
Apr 27 13:06:06 laptop dockerd[17029]: time="2019-04-27T13:06:06.415833044+02:00" level=warning msg="grpc: addrConn.transportMonitor exits due to: context canceled" module=grpc
```

Apart from that, I see nothing of interest in the system logs, `syslog` nor `dmesg`.

Docker CE was installed using [this procedure](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) (from the official docker repos) and is up-to-date. System info:

```
me@laptop:/tmp/test$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056
me@laptop:/tmp/test$ uname -a
Linux laptop 4.4.0-146-generic #172-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 3 09:00:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There have been no system changes lately, apart from the routine system upgrades. There *might* have been a kernel upgrade yesterday, IIRC.

Things I have tried:

1. Upgrading and downgrading docker to several versions;
2. Building a simple `Dockerfile` with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .` (gives the error above):

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN \
--mount=type=cache,target=/data \
echo hello
```

3. Removing the `--mount` line from the `Dockerfile` and build with `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build .` (gives the error above);
4. Building (obviously without the `--mount`) with `docker build .` (this works).

So the problem is with buildkit only. Anyone else seeing this and/or has a suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you post this in the docker forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the docker hub breach:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19763413

Bug on [BuildKit repo](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/967)

Started happening to me also, fixed by setting the version on the experimental syntax line:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you for the pointer. Meanwhile the issue on github has been resolved and a new buildkit image has been published: this solves the problem, and I only needed to rebuild without any modifications to the code.